# (Python) socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets

I'm not sure whats wrong with this code I keep getting that socket.gaierror error ;\ .

```
import sys
import socket
import random

filename = "whoiservers.txt"

server_name = random.choice(list(open(filename)))

print "connecting to %s..." % server_name

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server_name, 43))
s.send(sys.argv[1] + "\r\n")
response = ''
while True:
    d = s.recv(4096)
    response += d
    if d == '':
        break
s.close()
print
print response


    s.connect((server_name, 43))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

#### Update:

After adding `server_name = random.choice(list(open(filename)))[:-1]` I dont get that socket.gaierror anymore but I get:

> socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
>   rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
>   ailed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is a newline at the end of `server_name`.

If the format of your file `whoiservers.txt` is one hostname on each line then you need to strip the newline at the end of the hostname before passing it to `s.connect()`

So, for example, change the open line to:

```
server_name = random.choice(list(open(filename)))[:-1]
```

Comment: Weird. I was having this problem then this helped me fix it. This is what I had in my code: `mailserver = "foobar" #comment`. So to fix the problem, I deleted some characters at the end of the server name in my code: `mailserver = "fooba #comment`. Then I added those characters back: `mailserver = "foobar" #comment`. I also did the same from `socket.connect((mailserver, 587))` to `socket.connect((mailserve87))` and back to `socket.connect((mailserver, 587))`. After that, the problem was fixed. It seems that there was an invisible newline character somewhere between those characters. WEIRD!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a firewall in between you and these servers that is blocking the request?  The last error you posted leads one to believe that it cannot connect to the server at all...